# Hausdorffness on Topological Quotient Group

Tags: harmonic-analysis, topological-groups, separation-axioms

Let $G$ is a topological group i.e. operation of the group and inverse are continuous wrt topology.

I should show that if $G$ is Hausdorff then $G/N$ is Hausdorff where $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Is it valid with only normalness of $N$?

My attempt :

Let $x_1,x_2 \in G$

$x_1H \neq x_2H \Rightarrow x_1 \neq x_2 $ then since $G$ is Hausdorff there exists a neighborhood of $x_1$ say $V_1$ and there exists a neighborhood of $x_2 $ say $V_2$ such that $V_1\cap V_2 = \emptyset $. Also let $\pi$ is the projection which creates the topology of quotient. $\pi : G \to G/H$ Also I’ve shown that $\pi$ is open function but I don’t know how can I find disjoint nbds for $G/H$

Thanks in advance and pardon me for any mistake

Comment: In a topological group, Hausdorff = Singeltons closed so you can try to prove that as well.

Comment: I think you must ask that $N$ is closed in $G$ in the topological sense for this to be true.

Comment: @ε--δ I’ve show that as well but this property you said is coming after my question thus I cannot use it

Comment: @ε--δ Yes I meant “can I say this without closedness of N with “is it valid with only normalness of N”?

Comment: I think not, but I'm not 100% sure. Let's wait for the experts to arrive.

Comment: @ε--δ Thanks a lot for your efforts :)

Comment: Compute a case where $N$ is not closed.

Comment: Actually for $G$ arbitrary topological group (not necessarily Hausdorff), and $H$ subgroup (not necessarily normal), $G/H$ is Hausdorff **if and only if** $H$ is closed.

Comment: @YCor Thank you but I am not asking this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is false without closedness of $N$: take $G=(\Bbb R,+)$, $N=\Bbb Q$ then $G{/}N$ is indiscrete and uncountable, so certainly not even $T_0$, let alone Hausdorff. Open maps do not preserve Hausdorffness (as we see an example of here).